# Programmatically get list of all symbols in VS Code workspace for custom extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VS Code's quick view you can type `#mySymbol` to search your workspace for a symbol named `mySymbol`. I'd like to get these symbol results programmatically but don't see a way via the API to do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the [`vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands) for this:

> `vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider` - Execute all workspace symbol provider.
>
> - *query* - Search string
> - *(returns)* - A promise that resolves to an array of SymbolInformation instances.

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider", "mySymbol").then(
    function (symbols: vscode.SymbolInformation[]) {
        // do something with the symbols
    }
);
```

Note that some symbol provider implementations may not return any results if the search query is an empty string.

Comment: Is it possible to get the list of ALL workspace symbols?

Comment: Empty array (TypeScript).

Comment: You mean that's the result you get for an empty `query` string?

Comment: The API docs for `query` state: "A query string, can be the empty string in which case all symbols should be returned.", so this would be a bug in the TypeScript extension.